# Do we divide by n when we calculate forecast or prediction mean squared error?

Tags: prediction, mse

I'm so used to statistical packages calculating this for me that I forgot how to do this manually.  To calculate the prediction MSE, do we divide by n?  Most formulas just say determine the expectation.  Not sure if we need to adjust n by anything.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Divide what by $n$? By what $n$? In what context?

Comment: I figured it out.  It's just the mean of the squared deviations, no need to adjust n.